# how to use aviary photo editor in eclipse

Tags: android

I am new in Android Programming. How to use aviary photo editor in eclipse? I had downloaded Aviary Gradle sdk from their site and while importing that to my workspace shows error and could not find any proper tutorial based on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the following tutorials which describes the use of aviary sdk using eclipse

https://developers.aviary.com/docs/android/setup-guide#

http://oilcut123.pixnet.net/blog/post/357909806-teach-u-how-to-import-aviary-sdk-into-your-own-project---tut